# Specify columns to output with Pandas Merge function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['dog', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                'value': [5, 6, 7, 8],
               'valuea': [9, 10, 11, 12],
               'valueb': [13, 14, 15, 16]})
```

I would like to merge these 2 dataframes based on 'value'. However I don't want the result to give me all of the columns in df2. I would like to keep the one with the 'valuea' column  header but not the one with 'valueb' column header as per the squared output in the image.

[image]

The code I have tried is

```
df1.merge(df2, on ='value')
```

Is there a way exclude column with header = valueb using parameters in the merge function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot exclude columns with a parameter in the `merge` function.

Try these approaches instead:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2).drop(columns=['valueb'])
```

```
pd.merge(df1, df2.drop(columns=['valueb']))
```